# Prove that a tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius at the point of contact

Tags: complex-analysis

It is an exercise of Ahlfors. You can find it at the end of the section about oriented circles.

Can you help me to give an analytical proof of this fact?

Comment: Say you are looking at the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ around the origin. Consider the curve $\gamma\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{S}^1$ given by $\gamma(t)= e^{2\pi it}$. The derivative $\gamma'(t)$ gives a vector tangent to the circle at the point $\gamma(t)$. On the other hand, the radius at $\gamma(t)$ is given by the vector $\gamma(t)$. So can you compute $\gamma'(t)$ and see if it is perpendicular to $\gamma(t)$?

Comment: Extend the radius to a line in both directions. Suppose the tangent is not at right-angles. Reflect everything in the radius line. The circle and the radius are reflected into themselves. The tangent line is not, so you get two different tangents through the same point. Which may be a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to prove it using cross ratios.

Without loss of generality, we can let the circle in question be the unit circle, and the tangent be $z = 1 + b t$, where $b$ is a complex number with $|b| = 1$, and $t$ is real. The radius through the point of contact is simpy the real axis. We need to show that $b$ is purely imaginary.

We pick three points on the circle: $-1$, $1$, $i$. Every point on the tangent (except 1) will have to be on the same side of the circle. This means $\mathrm{Im}(z, -i, 1, -1)$ must not change sign.

We have, remembering $|b|=1$,

$\mathrm{Im}(z, -i, 1, -1) = \mathrm{Im}\frac{1+bt-1}{1+bt+1}\frac{-i+1}{-i-1} = \mathrm{Re}\frac{bt}{2+bt}=\frac{t^2 + 2 (\mathrm{Re}b) t}{|2+bt|^2}$.

The condition that there is no sign change is thus equivalent to $\mathrm{Re}b=0$. (Free free to some infinitesimal $t$ to see why this is true.)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

WLOG, assume we have a circle centered at the origin and with radius $\;r\;:\;\{(a\cos\theta\,,\,a\sin\theta)\;$

$$\left\langle\,(a\cos\theta\,,\,a\sin\theta)\,,\,(-a\sin\theta\,,\,a\cos\theta)\,\right\rangle=0\;,\;\;\text{so}\ldots$$

The above though hardly refers to what Ahlfors does in that part of his book...